# Windows 7 - One User Account Cannot Change Password

Tags: windows-7, passwords, user-accounts

We have a computer running Windows 7, with one user account on it.  The user reported changing her login password, and after having done so, she now cannot log in to Windows.

In troubleshooting, we found that her old password still works.  Okay, she must have just not changed it correctly. But we changed it again (in User Accounts in the Control Panel) and found that once again, after a reboot the new password does not work, but the old one does.

If I remove the password entirely, after a reboot the system logs in without prompting for a password.  After testing that, I again created the new password, rebooted, and once again, the new password doesn't work, but the old original one still does.

I created a second user account from scratch, and the new account does not have this issue.

Any way to clear the corruption out of the existing user account?  Would rather not have to create an all new account if possible, as there's multiple account-specific programs in use, and getting them all migrated would be tedious.

Comment: Local or Domain user?

Comment: backup the user profile, delete the user, and recreate them. Then delete the registery key indicated here: http://superuser.com/questions/512484/how-do-i-force-windows-7-to-create-a-new-domain-profile-with-same-name-as-an-exi/512488#512488 . Reboot, and try recreating the user account.

Comment: It is a Local account. Computer is not joined to a domain